# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to use resource attributes table in IF block. Error is in second if block:

> Multi-part identifier 'ra.Start_dt' could not be bound

I have used the alias name i.e. ra, even then I get this error. Can someone help me out with this code?

```
IF (@toyear - @fromyear = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @vacsql = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
                       a.resourceID, r.EnterpriseID, r.FullName, 
                       dbo.fnGetWorkOrdersByResourceID(a.resourceID,' + 
                          CAST(@tomonth AS VARCHAR(2)) + ',' +
                          CAST(@toyear AS VARCHAR(4)) + ') AS WorkOrder,         
                       dbo.fnGetDomainsByResourceID(a.resourceID,' + 
                          CAST(@tomonth AS VARCHAR(2)) + ',' +
                          CAST(@toyear AS VARCHAR(4)) + ') AS Domain,  
                       l.Offshore_Ind,
                       SUM(ISNULL(a.Totals, 0)) AS TOTALHOURS
                   FROM 
                       [Actuals] AS a 
                   JOIN
                       [Resources] AS r ON a.ResourceID = r.ResourceID 
                   JOIN 
                       Resource_Attributes AS ra ON r.ResourceID = ra.ResourceID 
                   JOIN
                       Location_LU AS l ON ra.LocationID = l.LocationID 
                   JOIN 
                       Roll_On_Off AS ro ON r.ResourceID = ro.ResourceID
                   WHERE 
                       (a.TaskName = ''Leave'') 
                       AND a.CalYear = ' + CAST(@toyear AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
                     ' AND CalMonthNum <= ' + CAST(@tomonth AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                     ' AND CalMonthNum >= ' + CAST(@frommonth AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                     'AND (CONVERT(datetime, ro.End_Dt)) > (CONVERT(datetime, '''+cast(concat(@frommonth,'/01/',@toyear) as varchar(10))+'''))
                           (CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt))<=(CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,ra.End_dt))>=(CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate))
                           GROUP BY ra.AttributeID,a.ResourceID,r.EnterpriseID,r.FullName,l.offshore_Ind'

                           if((CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt))<=(CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,ra.End_dt))>=(CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate)) AND CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt) between (CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate)))
                            BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO @vacTable EXECUTE sp_executesql @vacsql,
                                                    N'@StartDate varchar(25), @EndDate varchar(25)',
                                                    @StartDate,
                                                    @EndDate;
                            END
```

Comment: Please check for missing  AND just before  (CONVERT(datetime,ra.start_dt))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

```
 if (@toyear-@fromyear=0)

                       BEGIN
                              Set @vacsql = 'SELECT DISTINCT a.resourceID,r.EnterpriseID,r.FullName, dbo.fnGetWorkOrdersByResourceID(a.resourceID,'+ CAST(@tomonth AS VARCHAR(2))+','+CAST(@toyear AS VARCHAR(4)) +') as WorkOrder,         
                           dbo.fnGetDomainsByResourceID(a.resourceID,'+ CAST(@tomonth AS VARCHAR(2))+','+CAST(@toyear AS VARCHAR(4)) +') as Domain, l.Offshore_Ind,SUM(ISNULL(a.Totals,0)) AS TOTALHOURS
                           FROM [Actuals] AS a join [Resources] AS r on a.ResourceID=r.ResourceID 
                           join Resource_Attributes as ra on r.ResourceID=ra.ResourceID 
                           join Location_LU as l on ra.LocationID=l.LocationID 
                           join Roll_On_Off as ro on r.ResourceID=ro.ResourceID
                           WHERE (a.TaskName=''Leave'') AND a.CalYear='+CAST(@toyear as varchar(10))+' AND CalMonthNum <='+CAST(@tomonth as varchar(10))+' AND CalMonthNum >='+CAST(@frommonth as varchar(10))+' 
                           AND (CONVERT(datetime,ro.End_Dt))>(CONVERT(datetime,'''+cast(concat(@frommonth,'/01/',@toyear) as varchar(10))+'''))
                           (CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt))<=(CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,ra.End_dt))>=(CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate))
                           GROUP BY ra.AttributeID,a.ResourceID,r.EnterpriseID,r.FullName,l.offshore_Ind'

                           if exists (select 1 from Resource_Attributes ra where (CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt))<=(CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,ra.End_dt))>=(CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate)) AND CONVERT(datetime,ra.Start_dt) between (CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate)) AND (CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate)))
                            BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO @vacTable EXECUTE sp_executesql @vacsql,
                                                    N'@StartDate varchar(25), @EndDate varchar(25)',
                                                    @StartDate,
                                                    @EndDate;
                            END
                            END
```